# Divide in annotated queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an annotated queryset

```
qs.annotate(num_x=Count('x', distinct=True), num_y=Count('y', distinct=True))
```

Can I also get `num_x / num_y`?

I have tried

```
qs.annotate(
  num_x=Count('x', distinct=True),
  num_y=Count('y', distinct=True),
  num_x_per_y=Count(F('x') / F('y'))
)
```

and

```
qs.annotate(
  num_x=Count('x', distinct=True),
  num_y=Count('y', distinct=True),
  num_x_per_y=num_x / num_y
)
```

but it doesn't work.

I know I can calculate it with a filter in the template but isn't it possible to do with annotate?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `extra()` query-method here. There is quite a nice explanation in [Django ORM equivalent for this SQL..calculated field derived from related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690343/django-orm-equivalent-for-this-sql-calculated-field-derived-from-related-table) already.